# How to add a JWT to sesion storage on the browser?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to add a `JWT` to the session storage, I'm working with `PHP` and `Laravel` (I'm pretty new with both technologies), and I am using the `Auth` routes for basic registration and login. I have already created the part where the token is generated with the user info after the successful login. Still, I want to add that generated token to the web browser session storage. After that, the idea is to get it from the session storage, decode it and obtain the info in the `JWT.`

I added the JWT token generation on the `authenticated` method in the `AuthenticatesUsers` class.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // gets the email from the user
    $credentials = request(['email']);
    
    // generate the token with the email
    if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    // add the token to session storage?
}
```

I don't know how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're using Laravel then you can try their Session they have docu for it https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I don't knew about the Session, I'm looking it and looks like a better option than JWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of these method

```
// Retrieve a piece of data from the session...
$value = session('key');

// Specifying a default value...
$value = session('key', 'default');

// Store a piece of data in the session...
session(['key' => 'value']);

// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

// Via the global "session" helper...
 session(['key' => 'value']);
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I needed, but it's a good alternative.